# Converting to date in R

Tags: r

In R I have `data`

```
1/1/2014
1/1/2014
....
4/14/2016
```

I want a new dataset `data_new` that contain all entries with year 2016.
When I type `as.Date(data)` I get `"1-01-20" "1-01-20" ...` which I don't understand. How can I make this subset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did `as.Date(data)`, I am assuming `data` to be a character vector.

---

Use `year <- substring(as.Date(data, "%m/%d/%Y"), 1L, 4L)` to extract year information, then use `subset(data, year == "2016")` to get subset.

---

Why not simply use `grep("2016", data, value = TRUE)`?